# Serenity test not running with Serenity Parameterized Runner

Tags: java, junit, parameters, automated-tests, serenity-bdd

I am trying to run serenity test  with parameterized runner,

```
@RunWith(SerenityParameterizedRunner.class)
public class CloneViewTest {
   
    String val;
    public CloneViewTest(String testData) {
        val = testData;
    }

    protected Actor james = Actor.named("James");
    @Managed
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void jamesCanBrowseTheWeb() {
        james.can(BrowseTheWeb.with(driver));
    }

    @TestData
    public Collection<Object[]> testdata() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"cats"},
                {"dogs"},
                {"ferrets"},
                {"rabbits"},
                {"canaries"}
        });
        
    }

    @Test
    public void should_be_able_to_clone_views() {
        james.attemptsTo(Open.browserOn().the(Column_dictionaryPage.class));

    }
}
```

The problem is whenever is run this test using `mvn clean verify` Test is successful but no test is run. Also log shows skipping tests

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ -Automation ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ -Automation ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Hamza Y\IdeaProjects\-Assignment-Serenity-Screenplay\target\-Automation-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:integration-test (default) @ -Automation ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- serenity-maven-plugin:2.3.4:aggregate (serenity-reports) @ -Automation ---
[INFO] Test results for 0 tests generated in 1.7 secs in directory: file:/C:/Users/Hamza%20Y/IdeaProjects/-Assignment-Serenity-Screenplay/target/site/serenity
/
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO]  SERENITY TESTS : SUCCESS
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO] | Tests executed         | 0
[INFO] | Tests passed           | 0
[INFO] | Tests failed           | 0
[INFO] | Tests with errors      | 0
[INFO] | Tests compromised      | 0
[INFO] | Tests pending          | 0
[INFO] | Tests ignored/skipped  | 0
[INFO] ------------------------ | --------------
[INFO] | Total Duration         | 000ms
[INFO] | Fastest test took      | 000ms
[INFO] | Slowest test took      | 000ms
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
```

Also as shown in log no test is executed, failed or skipped. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You have most likely the wrong class name. Given you are using the default config, `verify` will run tests with patterns like `*IT.java`
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

rename you class to `CloneViewTestIT` and try again.